# simple c code ran through python produces wrong result

Tags: python, c, object, wrapper, shared

I have started a project where I need to wrap a piece of c code to run it through python in linux. I have started with a simple example, which should print 10. I can compile this example, but the ending result is not shown correct in python. Below I have described what I do and I sincerely hope that someone can help me out.

C code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double rand10();

double rand10() {
    double B = 10;
    return B;
}
```

python code:

```
from ctypes import *
libCalc = CDLL("./libcalci.so")
 
#call C function to check connection
libCalc.connect() 

r = libCalc.rand10()
print "r: ",r
```

And I create my shared object file as the following:

```
gcc -shared -o libcalci.so -fPIC example.c
```

Result from python:

```
r: 0
```

As you see python prints 0, but it should print 10.

Comment: C functions are assumed to retutn int. You need to set restype, as described here https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html

Comment: `print "r: ",r` isn't Python. This doesn't inspire confidence that the rest of your info in the question is actually what you're doing.

Comment: @Gene It's valid Python 2.

Comment: @Gene its valid python 2!!

Comment: Thanx @Paul Hankin. That was it!

Comment: @DavidHalley Thanks. I've only become a Python-ite since 3.  Never ran into this before.  I apologize for the wrong comment.